# Can I put and retrieve the user information to and from session into a Laravel custom user provider?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am not so into **PHP** and **Laravel** and I have the following problem, I came from Java.

I am following this tutorial to implement a **custom user provider**:

https://blog.georgebuckingham.com/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers/

I am using Laravel 5.3 version.

I briefly expain what I need: my Laravel application is only a front end application, all the business logic, included the user authentication, is performed by a Java back end application that exposes REST web services.

Performing a call to:

```
http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login
```

and passing **username** and **password** as basic authentication I obtain a **JSON** response like this that represent the logged user:

```
{
  "userName": "Painkiller",
  "email": "painkiller@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true
}
```

So, in my Laravel application, I have to perform this call and then parse the previous returned JSON object to generate the authenticated object into the front end application session.

To do this I have implemented the previous tutorial (and it seems to works) implementing this **custom user provider** class named **UserProvider** that implements the Laravel **IlluminateUserProvider** interface:

```
<?php

namespace App\Authentication;

use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as IlluminateUserProvider;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_encode;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_decode;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class UserProvider implements IlluminateUserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        // TODO: Implement retrieveById() method.
        \Log::info('retrieveById START');

        // PERFORM THE CALL TO MY BACK END WB SERVICE AND CREATE A NEW GenericUser USING THESE INFORMATION:

        $attributes = array(
            'id' => 123,
            'username' => 'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
            'password' => \Hash::make('SuperSecret'),
            'name' => 'Dummy User',
        );

        $user = new GenericUser($attributes);

        return $user;

    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        // TODO: Implement retrieveByToken() method.
        \Log::info('retrieveByToken START');
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        // TODO: Implement updateRememberToken() method.
        \Log::info('updateRememberToken START');
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) {

        // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.

        \Log::info('retrieveByCredentials START');
        \Log::info('INSERTED USER CREDENTIAL: '.$credentials['email'] . ' ' .$credentials['password']);

        $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

        $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
            [
                'auth' => [
                    'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
                    'pswd'
                ]
            ]);

        $dettagliLogin = json_decode($response->getBody());

        \Log::info('response: '.(json_encode($dettagliLogin)));

        //$user = new User('Pippo', 'pippo@google.com', true);

        $attributes = array(
            'id' => 123,
            'username' => 'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
            'password' => \Hash::make('SuperSecret'),
            'name' => 'Dummy User',
        );

        $user = new GenericUser($attributes);

        \Log::info('USER: '.(json_encode($user)));

        return $user;


    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // TODO: Implement validateCredentials() method.
        \Log::info('validateCredentials START');
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is only a preliminary test so the returned data are mocked.

It works in this way:

1) When the user insert his credential in the login page (http://localhost:8000/login) it is called the **retrieveByCredentials()** method:

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) {

    // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.

    \Log::info('retrieveByCredentials START');
    \Log::info('INSERTED USER CREDENTIAL: '.$credentials['email'] . ' ' .$credentials['password']);

    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

    $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
                'pswd'
            ]
        ]);

    $dettagliLogin = json_decode($response->getBody());

    \Log::info('response: '.(json_encode($dettagliLogin)));

    //$user = new User('Pippo', 'pippo@google.com', true);

    $attributes = array(
        'id' => 123,
        'username' => 'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
        'password' => \Hash::make('SuperSecret'),
        'name' => 'Dummy User',
    );

    $user = new GenericUser($attributes);

    \Log::info('USER: '.(json_encode($user)));

    return $user;

}
```

that performs a web service call to obtain the user information related to this user. Then these credential are verified by the **validateCredentials()** method (at this time it returns **true** every time). Finnaly it returns a **GenericUser** objct containing the information of the logged user (at this time are mocked because is a test and I have not yet paresed the **JSON** reeturned by my web service.

Then, when the user access to the next page (after the success login) it seems to me that is called the **retrieveById($identifier)** method, this:

```
public function retrieveById($identifier)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveById() method.
    \Log::info('retrieveById START');

    // PERFORM THE CALL TO MY BACK END WB SERVICE AND CREATE A NEW GenericUser USING THESE INFORMATION:

    $attributes = array(
        'id' => 123,
        'username' => 'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
        'password' => \Hash::make('SuperSecret'),
        'name' => 'Dummy User',
    );

    $user = new GenericUser($attributes);

    return $user;

}
```

At this time the logic is that it use the id of the previous logged user to perform a call to the back end web service, obtain again these information and create the same **GenericUser** object that will be returned to the next page that uses it. Now I have mock these userinformation.

Ok, this works but I can't do in this way for security reason.

So my idea is: when I retrieve the user information in the **retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)**, after have check that are correct, I will put this **GenericUser** object into session.

Then in the **retrieveById()** method I will retrieve these information from the session.

Can I do something like this? Could be a smart way? How can I put and retrieve an object\data into and from the session (I am not into PHP and front end).

Comment: The mentioned tutorial is now at https://www.georgebuckingham.com/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

When you log in a user using Laravel's authentication API, it is automatically stored in the application's session. So what you are doing is completely fine.

And you don't need to worry about methods like `retrieveByCredentials` fireing calls to your REST API when you get the user instance through `Auth::user()`. Every time this method is called, it checks if there is an user already loged in. If there is, it just returns the user, otherwise, it makes the necessary calls to find that user.

But I would suggest putting those calls to your REST API in another class. The `UserProvider` has only the `responsibility` of showing Laravel how to retrieve a user, so it should make use of `delegation` to call other objects to do the dirty work of finding something somewhere.

You can checkout more about how the `session Auth` class work in the source of laravel:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it. It needs improvements yet but at least can be useful as a general guideline.

> Notes: I'm using PHP 8 and taking advantage of constructor property promotion, so maybe you'll have to assign the instance variables. I'm also using Laravel 8.

1. Implement your API gateway that implements the method:

```php
function authenticate(string $username, string $password): ?APIUser {}
```

Create an API user model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

final class APIUser implements Authenticatable
{

    function __construct(
        private $id,
        private $username,
        private $password,
        private $access_token,
        private $remember_token,
        private $expires_in,
        private $platform_id,
    ) {
        $this->password = Hash::make($this->password);
    }


    function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    function getAccessToken()
    {
        return $this->access_token;
    }

    function getExpiresIn()
    {
        return $this->expires_in;
    }

    function getPlatformId()
    {
        return $this->platform_id;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Authenticatable section
     * 
     */

    /**
     * Get the name of the unique identifier for the user.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'id';
    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        $this->remember_token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     * @param string $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }
}
```

2. Create the user provider:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use App\Ports\AppAPIGateway;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class APIUserProvider implements UserProvider
{
    function __construct(
        private AppAPIGateway $api,
        private Session $session
    ) {
    }

    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        if ($this->session->has('user')) {
            return $this->session->get('user');
        }
        return;
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        Log::info('APIUserProvider: retrieveByToken (not implemented)');
        return null;
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        $user->setRememberToken($token);
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (
            !array_key_exists('username', $credentials)
            ||
            !array_key_exists('password', $credentials)
        ) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Could not retrieve credentials: missing parameters');
        }

        $user = $this->api->authenticate(
            $credentials['username'],
            $credentials['password']
        );

        $this->session->put('user', $user);
        $this->session->save();

        return $user;
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        if (
            !array_key_exists('username', $credentials)
            ||
            !array_key_exists('password', $credentials)
        ) {
            throw new AuthorizationException('Could not validate credentials: missing parameters');
        }

        return
            $user->getUsername() == $credentials['username']
            && Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
}
```

3. Modify `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::provider('api_driver', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new APIUserProvider(
                $app->make('App\Ports\AppAPIGateway'),
                $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session')
            );
        });
    }
```

4. Enable this new provider in `config/auth.php`:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api_guard',
        'passwords' => 'api_provider',
    ],
...
    'guards' => [
        'api_guard' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'api_provider',
        ],
    ],
...
    'providers' => [
        'api_provider' => [
            'driver' => 'api_driver',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

When you did do

```
$user = new GenericUser($attributes);
```

You can follow with

```
Auth::login($user);
```

Now all your User attributes are stored in session and can be retrieved by calling

```
$user = Auth::user();
```